# Tests for a POJO class ProgressableItem

Tags: java, android, junit

I have tests for simple POJO class `ProgressableItem` (i.e. the one which has attributes total work and work done).

I use JUnit 3 (it's from Android application).

```
public class ProgressableItemTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    private ProgressableItem item;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        item = new ProgressableItem("item", "test item", 0, 100);
    }


    public void testNotEquals() {
        ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentName = copyOf(item);
        itemWithDifferentName.setName("Not the same " + item.getName());
        assertThat(itemWithDifferentName, not(item));
        ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentDescription = copyOf(item);
        itemWithDifferentName.setDescription("Not the same " + item.getDescription());
        assertThat(itemWithDifferentDescription, not(item));
        ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentProgress = copyOf(item);
        itemWithDifferentName.setProgress(item.getProgress() + 1);
        assertThat(itemWithDifferentProgress, not(item));
        ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentMax = copyOf(item);
        itemWithDifferentName.setMax(item.getMax() + 1);
        assertThat(itemWithDifferentMax, not(item));
    }

    private static ProgressableItem copyOf(ProgressableItem item) {
        return new ProgressableItem(item.getName(), item.getDescription(), item.getProgress(), item.getMax());
    }

}


public interface Handler<T> {
    void handle(T obj);
}
```

Then I modified it into:

```
public void testNotEquals() {
    for (Handler<ProgressableItem> progressableItemModifier : PROGRESSABLE_ITEM_MODIFIERS) {
        ProgressableItem differentItem = copyOf(item);
        progressableItemModifier.handle(differentItem);
        assertThat(differentItem, not(item));
    }
}

private static final Collection<? extends Handler<ProgressableItem>>
        PROGRESSABLE_ITEM_MODIFIERS = Arrays.asList(
                new Handler<ProgressableItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ProgressableItem obj) {
                        obj.setName("Not the same " + obj.getName());
                    }
                },
                new Handler<ProgressableItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ProgressableItem obj) {
                        obj.setDescription("Not the same " + obj.getDescription());
                    }
                },
                new Handler<ProgressableItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ProgressableItem obj) {
                        obj.setProgress(obj.getProgress() + 1);
                    }
                },
                new Handler<ProgressableItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ProgressableItem obj) {
                        obj.setMax(obj.getMax() + 1);
                    }
                }
);
```

But now I have many more lines of code.

Which of the two options is better? Should I separate the test method into 4 small methods? Is there no need to check each case?

Comment: Loops inside unit tests are *not done*. You want one test for each scenario, otherwise when one test fails, you're left to guess which one it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of tips for unit testing:

- One test case per subject: so you should definitely split the cases
- Ideally no logic at all: avoid loops
- Duplication is acceptable: clarity is most important

I would write this way:

```
public void testNotEquals_IfNameChanged() {
    ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentName = copyOf(item);
    itemWithDifferentName.setName("Not the same " + item.getName());
    assertThat(itemWithDifferentName, not(item));
}

public void testNotEquals_IfDescriptionChanged() {
    ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentDescription = copyOf(item);
    itemWithDifferentName.setDescription("Not the same " + item.getDescription());
    assertThat(itemWithDifferentDescription, not(item));
}

public void testNotEquals_IfProgressChanged() {
    ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentProgress = copyOf(item);
    itemWithDifferentName.setProgress(item.getProgress() + 1);
    assertThat(itemWithDifferentProgress, not(item));
}

public void testNotEquals_IfMaxChanged() {
    ProgressableItem itemWithDifferentMax = copyOf(item);
    itemWithDifferentName.setMax(item.getMax() + 1);
    assertThat(itemWithDifferentMax, not(item));
}
```

Since you never change `item`, you don't really need the `setUp` method:

```
private final ProgressableItem item = new ProgressableItem("item", "test item", 0, 100);
```

Of course just because it's `final` nothing prevents you from mutating it.

To be extra safe and stay efficient, you could create an unmodifiable `ProgressableItem`, for example:

```
private final ProgressableItem item = new ProgressableItem("item", "test item", 0, 100) {
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // ... + the other setters too
};
```